# multiples of the same nodes but have them not connected

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, nodes

Currently i have two colors cirlces (red and green) moving from the right side of my screen to the left. Now these circles or nodes are being called using this function

```
-(void)move {
if(_dead)
    return;
int random = rand() % 2;

NSLog(@"int:%d",random);

if (random == 0) {
_enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"greeny"];


       _enemy.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+200,
                                      CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    _enemy.size = CGSizeMake(70, 70);
    _enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:35];
    _enemy.physicsBody.mass = 0;
    _enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = Collisiongreen;


        [_enemies addObject:_enemy];
        NSLog(@"Enemies%lu",(unsigned long)_enemies.count);
          [self addChild:_enemy];
[_enemy runAction:[SKAction moveByX:-900 y:0 duration:4]];
    [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Spawn.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];
    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                         [SKAction waitForDuration:1.4],
                                         [SKAction performSelector:@selector(move) onTarget:self],

                                       ]]];
        NSLog(@"Enemies%lu",(unsigned long)_enemies.count);

    }
    if (random == 1) {
        _enemyy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"redy"];
        _enemyy.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+200,
                                       CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        _enemyy.size = CGSizeMake(70, 70);
        _enemyy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:35];
        _enemyy.physicsBody.mass = 0;
        _enemyy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = Collisionred;


        [_enemies addObject:_enemyy];
        NSLog(@"Enemies%lu",(unsigned long)_enemies.count);
        [self addChild:_enemyy];
        [_enemyy runAction:[SKAction moveByX:-900 y:0 duration:4]];
        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Spawn.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];
        [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                             [SKAction waitForDuration:1.4],
                                             [SKAction performSelector:@selector(move) onTarget:self],



                                         ]]];
    NSLog(@"Enemies%lu",(unsigned long)_enemies.count);

}
```

I have it set up thanks to Roecrew ([touchesMoved on a specific moving object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668258/touchesmoved-on-a-specific-moving-object/22671307?noredirect=1#comment34658438_22671307)) That when I touch the green circle it will move with my finger.

My Problem: Whenever a green node is created after a green node or a red node is created after a red node, the previously created node looses all its attributes and can no longer be touched/moved or be removed when it hits the end of the screen which it is programed to do ([_enemy removeFromParent])
When a red node follows a green node or visversa everything works fine. Its only when the same color proceeds the same color. Is there anyway that I can create multiples of the same node but have them each be independent? Thanks!

Ps. the line that says [_enemies addObject:_enemy]; Doesn't seem to work because its not adding them to the array.

```
@interface MyScene : SKScene <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
  {

      bool *someBool;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *wall;

@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *node;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *field;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *okfield;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *board;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKLabelNode *seconds;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *enemy;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *enemyy;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *enemy1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *enemy2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *enemy3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *enemy4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *enemy5;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *enemy6;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TCProgressTimerNode *progressTimerNode1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TCProgressTimerNode *progressTimerNode2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TCProgressTimerNode *progressTimerNode3;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval startTime;




@end
@interface SKEmitterNode (fromFile)
+ (instancetype)orb_emitterNamed:(NSString*)name;
@end





@implementation MyScene{
    BOOL _dead;
    SKNode *_player;
    enum {

    Collisionbordered = 1<<1,
    Collisiongreen = 1<<2,
    Collisionred = 1<<3,
    Collisionbordergreen = 1<<4,


};
NSTimeInterval _startTime;
NSTimer *timerr;
 NSTimer *timer;
int currMinute;
int currSeconds;
SKLabelNode *myLabel;
int i;
int level;
 NSMutableArray *_enemies;
SKAction *go;
SKLabelNode *startlabel;
float changeInX;
float changeInY;
float lastX;
float lastY;
float changeInXX;
float changeInYY;
float lastXX;
float lastYY;}
```

Comment: Can I see you interface code?

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Nah, I mean your @interface.

Comment: KK I added it to the bottom

Comment: Make NSMutableArray *_enemies; a property

Comment: I did that but still when a green is created and another green is created the first green looses its attributes. As in when the green hits the wall if theres another green behind it, it will not be removed. Only if there is a red behind it will it be removed

Comment: Any ideas?? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: How are you implementing the contact delegate? Please post code for that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _enemy and _enemyy variables can point to only one node at a time. Hence, you cannot access the previous node when another node is created. When another green node is created, the _enemy variable points to the new node and the previously created node loses any way to be able to access it. Here are a few ways you can use to be able to access all nodes:

**1 - Use the _enemies array properly.**

The _enemies array is not working because it is probably not being initialised at the start of the scene. You need to call

```
_enemies = [NSMutableArray new];
```

in the `-initWithSize` method.

**2 - Set the name for each node**

Instead of adding each node to an array, you can simply set the name of each node. Like so:

```
_enemy.name = @"greenCircle"
```

Then, to access all nodes you can use the `-enumerateChildNodesWithName:` method.